# Node js commands don't work

Tags: node.js, command-line

The other day I could type commands on Node command prompt just fine then commands stopped, I dont know what happened or what I had changed. So today I tried and I still get the below message

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I reinstalled Node and still same problem. I cannot change directory when I run

```
cd ~
```

or

```
ls
```

but I can check node version just fine.

```
node -v
```

## newbie

Comment: what happens when you type `echo $PATH`?

Comment: i get $PATH on next line @mad.meesh

Comment: my guess is your path is broken... with a text editor check your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and look for any `exports` relating to the variable `$PATH`

Comment: `export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"` found that in .bash_profile and I think i dont have .bashrc

Comment: neither of those relate to your `$PATH`... assuming you checked both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, what about `.profile`?

Comment: i only have `.bash_history`, `.node_repl_history` and `git-bash-completion.bash` and they dont have any exports. Also just noticed the same commands dont execute on MS Command Prompt but they do in GitBash, that is `cd ~` and `ls`

Comment: hold up. you’re on windows?

Comment: yup i am on windows 10

Comment: ok tap the `windows` button and then search for `environment variables` then find `edit` and then in the list of global variables look for the `PATH` variable.. i'm not on windows machine right now so cannot give you step by step instructions, sorry. you can search google for info on this though and maybe you will find something to fix the issue.

Comment: yah I added `C:\Windows\System32` to `path` and restart and still same problem. But thx will keep looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated commands are for linux/unix the Windows equivalent are as follows

```
cd ~     use   cd /
```

and

```
ls       use   dir
```